# Jake Wharton's LinePageIndicator does not restart after a view recycles

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter, viewpagerindicator

I am having a problem with the `ListView` adapter. I am trying to develop a simple timeline view. I have decided to use `ListView` and `BaseAdapter` for it, in order to efficiently show items in the vertical row. Everything seems to be fine but there is a problem with the reuse of views used to visualize items in the list. Each item has three `TextView` (Title, Details and Story), `ViewPager` which I am using to display photos and Jake Wharton's `LinePageIndicator` to show how many photos are there and which of them is currently displayed.

There are always right pictures loaded in the `ViewPager` and they are swiped from left to the right, however the indicator does not work right. Sometimes is shows that there are two photos although there is only one (this happens because the previous view had two photos) and it does not show that the first photo in the `ViewPager` is currently presented. It shows the last current position in the `ViewPager` from the previous view.

Obviously there is a problem with the indicator and it should be somehow restarted every time when a view recycles. I have already looked in the `LinePageIndicator` source and seen that `setViewPager(...)` method has this

```
if (mViewPager != null) {
    //Clear us from the old pager.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(null);
}
```

but obviously it does not help…

Finally here is my getView(...) method

```
...
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView txtTimelineItemTitle;
        TextView txtTimelineItemDetails;
        TextView txtTimelineItemText;
        ViewPager viewPager;
        LinePageIndicator indicator;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.timeline_item, parent, false);
            txtTimelineItemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeline_item_title);
            txtTimelineItemDetails = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeline_item_details);
            txtTimelineItemText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeline_item_text);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeline_view_pager);
            indicator = (LinePageIndicator) convertView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
            convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder(context, txtTimelineItemTitle, txtTimelineItemDetails, txtTimelineItemText, viewPager, indicator));
        } else {
            ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            txtTimelineItemTitle = viewHolder.txtTimelineItemTitle;
            txtTimelineItemDetails = viewHolder.txtTimelineItemDetails;
            txtTimelineItemText = viewHolder.txtTimelineItemText;
            viewPager = viewHolder.viewPager;
            indicator = viewHolder.indicator;
        }

        Story story = (Story) getItem(position);
        txtTimelineItemTitle.setText(story.getTitle());
        txtTimelineItemDetails.setText(Utils.dateFormat.format(stories.get(position).getDate()) + ", " + stories.get(position).getLocation());
        txtTimelineItemText.setText(story.getText());

        if (story.getImages().isEmpty()) {
            viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            indicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(context);
            imageAdapter.updateImages(story.getImages());
            viewPager.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
            indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
...
```

Has anyone of you already encountered issue like this? How could it be fixed and if not, is there an alternative?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Since this was very important for me, I have continued with exploring source code of the `LinePageIndicator`. I have seen that besides of the method `setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)` there is also method `setViewPager(ViewPager view, int initialPosition)` which as you can see allows you to set the current item in the `ViewPager`. I have changed only one line in the code above 
and it solved my issue.

```
indicator.setViewPager(viewPager, 0); //always start from the first item in the ViewPager
```